# Add-on SDK Toolbar Button does not work in second window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm a JavaScript beginner, so I tried to create a Firefox Toolbar Button with the [add-on builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org). The button works fine and shows a popup, but when I open a second Firefox window, the button is not displayed.

The Code:

```
exports.main = function() { 
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = self.data;
//  var tabs = require('tabs');



function listTabs() {
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
for each (var tab in tabs)
console.log(tab.url);
}



var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

// This module exports a single constructor function Panel which constructs a new panel.
// A panel is a dialog. Its content is specified as HTML and you can execute scripts in it,
// so the appearance and behaviour of the panel is limited only by what you can do using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
var toolbar_popup = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width:200,
    height:280,
    contentURL: data.url("popup.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('js/jquery.js'), data.url('js/jquery.cookie.js'), data.url('js/popup.js')],
    contentScriptWhen:'ready',
    contentScript: " "+
  "self.port.on('curTabMsg', function(curTabMsg) {" +
    "main(curTabMsg['curTab']);" +
  "});"
});



// creating toolbarbutton via including toolbar library Toolbar Buttons.
// Through this an Icon has to be created on the toolbar with image name gse_icon_16x16.png
var tbb = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
    id: "XXXXXX",
    label: "XXXXXXX",
    image: data.url("icon16.png"),
    panel: toolbar_popup,
    onClick: function() {   
  toolbar_popup.port.emit("curTabMsg",{'curTab': tabs.activeTab.url}); 
}
});



if (require('self').loadReason == "install") {
    tbb.moveTo({
        toolbarID: "nav-bar",
        forceMove: false // only move from palette
    });
}

toolbar_popup.on("show", function()  {
    toolbar_popup.port.emit("show", {
        version:self.version
        });
});

};
```

Why doesn't the button show in the second window?

Comment: You you have a link to your builder. Also, there are about a zillion modified forks of the library around, the original being "Toolbar Buttons" by erikvold. Testing your code with that one works for me: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/203410/latest/

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I used the wrong library. I used "Toolbar Button Complete" but with Toolbar Buttons" by erikvold the code works.

Comment: Ok, this is not working. Why doesn't the button show in the Firefox 23.01 / Windows? In Fireworks 23 on Ubuntu it works fine. The Link: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/203652/latest/